# Java Spring rate limiter block specific duration when ratio reached

Tags: java, spring, rate-limiting, resilience4j, bucket4j

Currently I have a requirement: Apply rate limiter for an API. If this API get called over 100 times per 5 sec then the API will be blocked for 10 mins.
I don't know if there is any java lib can fullfill this requirement. If the requirement is "Allow 100 calls per 5 sec" or "Allow 100 calls per 10 min" then I can either user Bucket4j:

```
Bandwidth b = Bandwidth.classic(100, Refill.intervally(100, Duration.ofSeconds(5)));
//Bandwidth b = Bandwidth.classic(100, Refill.intervally(100, Duration.ofMinutes(10)));
Bucket bk = Bucket.builder().addLimit(b).build();

//then
if(bk.tryConsume(1)) {
    //stuff
} else {
    throw
}
```

or Resilence4j:

```
RateLimiterConfig config = RateLimiterConfig.custom()
            .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .limitForPeriod(100)
            .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .build();
RateLimiterRegistry rateLimiterRegistry = RateLimiterRegistry.of(config);
RateLimiter rateLimiterWithCustomConfig = rateLimiterRegistry
            .rateLimiter("name2", config);
CheckedRunnable restrictedCall = RateLimiter
            .decorateCheckedRunnable(rateLimiterWithCustomConfig, this::doStuff);

//then
Try.run(restrictedCall).onFailure(throwable -> throw new RuntimeException());
```

But the requirement is "Allow 100 calls per 5 sec, if more, block 10 min". Is there any lib can work? Please suggest me a solution for this case. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently [this feature for `Bucket4j`](https://github.com/bucket4j/bucket4j/issues/311) to block a bucket for a certain period of time. (I can say the same in `Resilence4j` but I'm not so sure!)

**So you should to maintain blacklisting manually.** (This will require more complex code improvements depending on the use case!)

However, I think using 2 different limits as below is better in terms of code cost. (You can keep the 10-minute period somewhat flexible and maintain the 5-second condition.)

```java
Bandwidth bandwidth1 = Bandwidth.classic(
        1200, Refill.intervally(
                1200, Duration.ofMinutes(10)));
Bandwidth bandwidth2 = Bandwidth.classic(
        100, Refill.intervally(
                100, Duration.ofSeconds(5)));

Bucket bucket = Bucket.builder()
        .addLimit(bandwidth1)
        .addLimit(bandwidth2)
        .build();
```

**If we want to make manual blacklisting a simple example**;

You can keep a record of the time in which the blocked. Then, you can write another class that checks when the unblocking date is reached:

```java
import io.github.bucket4j.Bandwidth;
import io.github.bucket4j.Bucket;
import io.github.bucket4j.Refill;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import static java.time.LocalDateTime.now;

public class BucketWithPenaltyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Bandwidth bandwidth = Bandwidth.classic(
                100, Refill.intervally(
                        100, Duration.ofSeconds(5)));

        Bucket bucket = Bucket.builder()
                .addLimit(bandwidth)
                .build();

        BucketWithPenalty bucketWithPenalty =
                new BucketWithPenalty(bucket, 
                        Duration.ofMinutes(10).getSeconds());

        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(400);
            if (bucketWithPenalty.tryConsume(1)) {
                System.out.println(String.format(
                        "[%s] %s", now(), 
                        "Ok."));
            } else {
                System.err.println(String.format(
                        "[%s] %s", now(), 
                        "Rate limit error!"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
import io.github.bucket4j.Bucket;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import static java.time.LocalDateTime.now;

public class BucketWithPenalty {

    private static Bucket bucket;
    private static Long blockingTimeSeconds;
    private static LocalDateTime unblockingDate;

    public BucketWithPenalty(Bucket bucket, Long blockingTimeSeconds) {
        this.bucket = bucket;
        this.blockingTimeSeconds = blockingTimeSeconds;
        this.unblockingDate = now();
    }

    public boolean tryConsume(long numTokens) {
        if (unblockingDate.isBefore(now())
                && bucket.tryConsume(numTokens)) {
            unblockingDate = now();
            return true;
        } else {
            if (!unblockingDate.isAfter(now())) {
                unblockingDate = now().plusSeconds(blockingTimeSeconds);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not my expectation. Your code is about two bandwidth running simultaneously. My expectation is, if more than 100 calls per 5 sec, then block 10min, otherwise do nothing

Comment: I've updated the comment to clarify a more.

Comment: I think it's valuable because there was a lot of need.